# How does loose coupling assist with unit-testing?

Tags: unit-testing, dependency-injection

I am referring to the following [blog](https://medium.com/@jecky999/understanding-tight-coupling-vs-loose-coupling-in-software-development-with-kotlin-examples-5fd3fa08a5cd) to understand tight coupling/loose coupling.
I understand the example given,

```
interface PaymentGateway {
  fun authenticate()
  fun processPayment(amount: Double)
  fun sendConfirmation()
}
class PayPalGateway: PaymentGateway {
  // Implementation of PayPalGateway
}
class PaymentProcessor(private val paymentGateway: PaymentGateway) {
  fun processPayment(amount: Double) {
    paymentGateway.authenticate()
    paymentGateway.processPayment(amount)
    paymentGateway.sendConfirmation()
  }
}
```

but I don't understand how it helps with unit-testing as state in the blog,

> 3. Better testability: Loosely coupled components are easier to isolate and test independently, enabling more comprehensive unit
>    testing and easier integration testing.

Answer (score 1):

One can infer from the interface name, `PaymentGateway`, that methods of that interface will be doing actions over the network, possibly even third party calls to something not even in your control. If that component was ***not*** loosely coupled, if it was instead hard-coded into `PaymentProcessor`, then it would be essentially impractical to create unit tests for `PaymentProcessor`. But because of the loosely coupled design, you can freely create unit tests where you pass in a mock `PaymentGateway` that either (a) does nothing or, more usefully, (b) does actions that facilitate testing.

As an example of the latter, say, for example you had this unit test:

```
Confirm authentication is done before processing payment
```

Then in your `PaymentGateway` mock you could make the `authenticate` method push its name "authenticate" onto a stack, and similarly make the `processPayment` push its name "processPayment" onto that same stack.
Then, after you call `PaymentProcessor.processPayment`, you would just need to check the order of those items on the stack.

Comment: Could you please explain why "If that component was not loosely coupled, if it was instead hard-coded into PaymentProcessor, then it would be essentially impractical to create unit tests for PaymentProcessor."?

Comment: Even if payment gateaway is tightly coupled, we can always mock the concrete class?

Comment: While some testing frameworks would allow mocking a concrete class, as you say, I do not think that is generally true of _all_ testing frameworks. But even so, that is inherently more complex than just being able, via dependency injection, to directly pass in a test class. If, as I suggested in my original example, you want to manipulate local test data, that is straightforward with DI but would be trickier without it.